# What is the preferred practice for enabling Checkstyle for Jenkins?

Tags: ant, jenkins, checkstyle

Hi guys : I noticed that there is an ant task for checkstyle

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html

I want checkstyle to run in my Ant build, which is on jenkins.

Unfortunately, the instructions are somewhat cryptic - with references to enabling project dependencies , modules, and other ant-specific configurations.  I have a massive build file and I'm not really a build engineer - so I want to keep it simple without adding too much bload to the script.

Jenkins has a nice little button which supports displaying the checkstyle results, however, jenkins requires that you run the checkstyle and configure it yourself when you run a build.

What is the simplest way to modify my build.xml and ivy.xml ( i assume i will need to add checkstyle to ivy to get the jar remotely) to enable a basic checkstyle analysis of all the code base when builds are run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample of how to do it with help of just `Ant`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Build" default="build" basedir=".">

    <property file="props.properties"/>

    <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpath="${checkstyle.jar.path}"/>

    <target name="build" depends="checkstyle">
        <echo>Starting build</echo>
        <echo>Build finished</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="checkstyle">
        <echo>Starting checkstyle</echo>
        <checkstyle config="rules/sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <formatter type="xml" toFile="build/checkstyle_errors.xml"/>
        </checkstyle>
        <echo>Checkstyle finished</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The quote from [Checkstyle site](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html):

> failOnViolation -     Specifies whether the build will continue even if
>   there are violations. Defaults to "true".

You can download checkstyle-5.4-bin.zip from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkstyle/files/).
The distribution package contains `sun_checks.xml` - `checkstyle configuration that checks the sun coding conventions` and `checkstyle-x.x-all.jar` library with task engine.

Comment: @jayunit100 This line contains path to checkstyle jar. This jar contains the code of `checkstyle` ant task. The `checkstyle` is not core Ant Apache task, therefore it need to be included in classpath.

Comment: I think that you are using `Ivy` for storing project dependency, not for storing Ant toolkit libraries. I never used `jenkins`, but I think you can include ant script and set environments (properties) for its execution